# Php warning when running Silverstripe tests in web browser. "phpunit/scr/Framework/TestResult.php" failed to open

Tags: phpunit, silverstripe

I wish to run the tests in NetefxValidator, a Silverstripe module for form validation (http://netefx.de/module/netefxvalidator/).  I have installed a fresh version of Silverstripe CMS along with this module.  I open a browser at localhost:8888/dev/tests/ and can see all Silverstripe's tests and the NetefxValidator one. When I click on any test I receive php warnings and fatal errors (example below).  Any ideas please?

[11-Jul-2014 06:52:52 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Warning:  require_once(phpunit/scr/Framework/TestResult.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/dev/SapphireTestReporter.php on line 2
[11-Jul-2014 06:52:52 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'phpunit/scr/Framework/TestResult.php' (include_path='/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/parsers:/Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/thirdparty:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php') in /Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/dev/SapphireTestReporter.php on line 2
[11-Jul-2014 06:52:52 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Warning:  Cookie 'alternativeDatabaseName' can't be set. The site started outputting content at line 101 in /Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/dev/DebugView.php in /Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/control/Cookie.php on line 117
[11-Jul-2014 06:52:52 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Warning:  Cookie 'alternativeDatabaseNameIv' can't be set. The site started outputting content at line 101 in /Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/dev/DebugView.php in /Users/Base/Documents/Web Design/NetefxValidator/framework/control/Cookie.php on line 117

**My setup: **
Following the Silverstripe instructions (http://docs.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/testing/) I have installed PHPunit via Composer (composer update --dev) and can see it within the Vendor folder.  For good measure I also successfully installed PHPUnit in the terminal.

The next configuration step requires a phpunit.xml file in the project root.  Here is the starting point I found on github (https://github.com/silverstripe/doc.silverstripe.org/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist).  I have added NetefxValidator to the test suite:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="framework/tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true">

    <testsuite name="Default">
        <directory>netefxvalidator/code/tests</directory>
        <directory>cms/tests</directory>
        <directory>framework/tests</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="SS_TestListener" file="framework/dev/TestListener.php" />
    </listeners>

    <groups>
        <exclude>
            <group>sanitychecks</group>
        </exclude>
    </groups>

</phpunit>
```

How do I load the PHPunit class, in TestResult.php, that SapphireTestReporter.php requires?
Also, I believe that I need to give PHPunit access to the MySQL database.  Any tips please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will resolve the issue but have you setup a environment file with a entry in $_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING for your local site.
I was wondering if this is the reason it could not find the path to phpunit, see the link below for more info.

http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/environment-management

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @K Mayo for your advice.  I fished around and found that it was the wrong version of `PHPUnit`.  `Silverstripe 3.1.5` supports `PHPUnit 3.7`, not `4.2`.  Will submit a pull request to the `Silverstripe` docs to clarify.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Answer: Did not need to create a PHPunit class, in TestResult.php.  Uninstall PHPUnit 4.2.  Then, install PHPUnit 3.7. Open yoursite.com/dev/tests and run a test.